# Congruence $4x \equiv 2 \pmod 6$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

Is there a solution for the congruence $4x \equiv 2 \pmod 6$ ?
And how can I find inverse element for $4$, when I can not use Extended Euclidean algorithm, because $6$ and $4$ are divisible by $2$.

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could start by rewriting the congruence in equation form as follows

$$
4x\equiv 2 \pmod 6 \iff 4x=2+6\cdot k
$$

now you are dealing with a usual equation, here you can divide by $2$ to get

$$
2x=1+3\cdot k \iff 2x\equiv 1\pmod 3\iff \ 2\cdot2x\equiv 2\cdot 1\pmod 3
$$

which means

$$
x\equiv 2\pmod 3.
$$

But remember we needed a solution modulo $6$, so we need to check which numbers in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5 \}$ satisfies the above congruence an we easily find that $2$ and $5$ is congruent to $2$ modulo $3$ and these are our solutions.

Comment: Yes, in fact if you have $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $d=\gcd(a,b,n)$ you can divide $a,b,n$ by $d$ to  get $a'\equiv b'\pmod{n'}$ and keep equivalence in the way.

Answer (score 0):

$ 4x \equiv 2 \bmod 6 $ implies

- $ 4x \equiv 2 \bmod 2 $, which does not give any information
- $ 4x \equiv 2 \bmod 3 $, which reduces to $ x \equiv 2 \bmod 3 $

Conversely, every number of the form $x=3k+2$ is a solution of $ 4x \equiv 2 \bmod 6 $.

Therefore, $ 4x \equiv 2 \bmod 6 $ iff $x \equiv 2,5 \bmod 6 $.